# How to create Audit history table table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which update records. Can anyone help me how to create an audit table that will store previous data and updated data when an update takes place?

I have a stored procedure which updates the table, but I want to keep audit history of previous record and updated record in a separate table after the stored procedure is run. I just want to capture the changes the stored procedure made, in a separate table

Comment: You do it the same way you create any other table.  Determine the field names and datatypes, and create it with either a create table command, or the tools available in SSMS.

Comment: Create the history table by scripting the data table. Add a `HistoryKeyID int identity(1,1)` column as the PK of the history table. Add an `After Update Trigger` to the data table and insert the deleted records to the history table. If you insert the updated (inserted records), then you'll have duplicate data in the history table. Not sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to write a trigger function on that specific table.**

Check the below example,

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (Id int, customer_name varchar(50));

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(1, 'Jhon');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(2, 'Smith');

-- Create audit table 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTable](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OldValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NewValue] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Assume you have a customer table and want to insert a audit record whenever a changes made to customer table. Then write a trigger as follow,

```
CREATE TRIGGER Customer_Audit on Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO AuditTable(Id, OldValue, NewValue) 

select d.Id, d.customer_name, c.customer_name
from deleted d 
inner join Customer c
on d.Id = c.Id 

GO
```

Now whenever changes made to customer table, a audit record will insert to audit table as follow,

```
UPDATE Customer SET customer_name = 'Shamique' WHERE id = 2
```

[Output after update the record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYsl4.jpg)

Hope that is clear.

## Edited

Alter the table with updatedDate and updatedTime column then change trigger query as follow,

```
INSERT INTO AuditTable(Id, OldValue, NewValue, updateDate, updateTime) 
select d.Id, d.customer_name, c.customer_name, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101) as DatePart, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),108) as TimePart from deleted d inner join 
Customer c on d.Id = c.Id
```

If you need to add Date and Time as one, then simply you can use **getDate()** syntax in your select statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shamique. I dont have words to express my gratitude to you.. Thanks a alot for helping me.

Comment: Hi Shamique thanks for helping, i am trying to add update date and time column, could you please help me with that?

Comment: check the edited SQL query. Hope that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks alot brother . I will check this out tomorrow in my office. I will let you know. Thanks alot for your kind help.

Comment: Thanks @Shamique, it work like a charge. I am using both date and time together in one column so im using getdate() in select statement. Thanks alot for you time and help..

Comment: glad you made it and most welcome :)